# What are the phases that are executed during an msi upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am looking for the exact list of operations that are executed during an upgrade of an msi file, in terms of Wix standard actions (StartServices, RemoveFiles etc.).
I am asking because I want to insert to my wxs file some custom actions, and I need to know how to schedule them.

Thanks in advance,
Eitan

Comment: It may help to say what you want to do exactly. You can insert CAs only in the new MSI, so the that's the same as a non-upgrade. If this is about doing something before the older product is removed then you need to do it before the RemoveExistingProducts that is scheduled in your major upgrade element.

Comment: This is what I want to do: to create a temporary file when the upgrade starts, and to remove it when the upgrade ends, just before the program startup. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a very detailed discussion.  In general realize that during any given transaction (install, uninstall, repair, maintenance (feature install/uninstall), upgrade (major and minor) that any given component could be getting installed, reinstalled or removed.   Depending on the nature of the component, operations could be scheduled (immeadiate) and executed (deferred). This means that one or more of the standard actions you mentioned could be doing something.  In the case of a rollback they could be undoing something also.

I would start here:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/)

[Zataoca: Custom actions are (generally) an admission of failure.](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/zataoca-custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure/)

[Zataoca: Custom actions should be data driven](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/9/13/zataoca-custom-actions-should-be-data-driven/)

[Data Driven Managed Custom Actions made easy with DTF](http://blog.iswix.com/2008/05/data-driven-managed-custom-actions-made.html)

[Beam Me Up: Using JSON to serialize CustomActionData](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/10/beam-me-up-using-json-to-serialize.html)

It's a lot to cover but if you want to do it properly you want to write one or more custom tables to describe what needs to be done and have a join to the Component table to drive "when" it happens.  The custom actions then implement "how" it happens.   A custom action to query the tables and evaluate the component states to pass data to multiple custom actions to  perform the work, rollback the work and dispose (commit) of any artifacts that were saved off to support rollback or weren't safe to perform until the very end of the install (assuming rollback wasn't disabled).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. To focus my question, here is exactly what I want to do: to create a temporary file when the upgrade starts, and to remove that file when the upgrade ends, just before the program startup.

Comment: InstallShield supports this through a feature called Support Files.  Your file is stared in a custom table and a custom action is called to extract to a temp directory and assign a property (SUPPORTDIR) to that path.  Then when the install finishes another custom action is called to cleanup the file.  It works fairly well.  I would download an eval copy of InstallShield, author a simple MSI that does this and then edit it in ORCA to get an understanding of how to wire it all up.

Comment: If I understood what the temporary file was and how it was used I might be able to provide better suggestions.

Comment: The purpose of the temporary file is to that after the upgrade ends, my program will know if the upgrade ended properly, or if, for example, there was a reboot during the upgrade. At startup, my program can check if the file exists, and if it does, then the upgrade did not finish well.

Comment: Do you not trust MSI to do this for you?  Windows Installer rollback was designed to state consistency and this includes reboot handling.  I've written thousands of installs over the years and I've never needed to implement such a feature.

Comment: Do you mean that after the startup, I can only check the version of the program and trust that to indicate if the upgrade succeeded or not? Does that mechanism work in any case, or is it configurable? Do you have a link that describes that (specifically for reboot)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371370(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372059(v=vs.85).aspx
The Windows Installer has a concept of suspending and resuming an installation after a reboot and because the rollback files are stored in a special directory it's able to rollback after a reboot.  Give it a try on a VM sometime.   The only times this can be a problem is 1) If you are writing custom actions that MSI doesn't know about or 2)  if you are doing major upgrades and you schedule RemoveExistingProducts before CostInitialize.  But this is documented.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the documentation. Anyway, if I decide to use the temporary file, when is the right time to do that? I mean, what is the first standard action that is done (before it I will create the file), and what is the last standard action (after it I will delete the file)?